# Domain forwarding (sort-of)

Tags: .htaccess, hosting, dns

I have been attempting to set up magento on a shared hosting server that doesn't support innoDB, ergo its not been possible. The domain I want to use has also been registered with this rubbish hosting provider. (one[dot]com for anyones reference). So I thought I would be able to point this domain to a different hosting provider that DOES support it, but one[dot]com doesnt allow me to change nameservers for the domain. They just said this:

> You can only setup IP address, CNAME and web forwarding in our DNS settings but not change of nameservers

Would there be any way to change any of these settings or the .htaccess file so that, for example

> http://www.mydomain.com/folder/page.php?query=string

Would display a page from the other server

> http://xxx.xxx.xxx:xx/folder/page.php?query=string

I've created loads of sits doing all sorts but never really needed to other with the domain administration side of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change name servers to map a domain to a different server. If the "good" provider supports it (i.e. allows you to register a domain on the server that isn't hosted by the company), just switch the A and MX records to the new server's IP address.

You *do* need the cooperation of the "good" provider for this, though.

Answer (score 1):

If they're letting you set up the IP address, then setting the IP address of `www.mydomain.com` to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xx` should do the trick. On the other server, you'll need its webserver to be set up to serve `www.mydomain.com` as a virtual domain - if you're using a hosting provider they should do this for you; if not it should be fairly easy to set up (consult the manual of whichever web server software you're using).